# .bat file escape less than and greater than symbols echo statement

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a simple bash file to generate a specific structure (for php files) that is required on my job.

```
SET FILE_LIST=(Ex1.php Ex2.php)

FOR %%i IN %FILE_LIST% do echo ?php > %%i
FOR %%i IN %FILE_LIST% do echo. >> %%i
FOR %%i IN %FILE_LIST% do echo /* >> %%i
FOR %%i IN %FILE_LIST% do echo !IniHeaderDoc >> %%i
....
```

The thing is that the first line of FOR loop should write the open php tag

```
<?php
```

But I can't find the way to scape the "<" symbol. The same thing happens with closure of php tag...

Doing some research I read about that "<" and ">" symbols are not escapable on .bat files..

So, is there a way to escape these symbols?

Comment: Try it with `^<?php`

Comment: Thanks @jeb.. Both are absolutely right..